# How to automate run an mule application

Tags: mule

I have a mule flow and I want to automate the execution of the application without http listener
I want the mule application execute without enter "localhost:8081/app"
is it a way to do this?

[Screenshots of the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlmVN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your question, I can suggest the below steps

1) Add Composite source at the start of your flow.

2) Place the existing HTTP inbound endpoint into Composite source scope.

3) As an addition, add the quartz inbound endpoint into composite source scope and configure it at what time you want to run using cron expression.

This approach enables you option to trigger the flow using either HTTP URL or automated execution through quartz component using cron expression.

Please comment on this answer if you feel my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want the app to run at scheduled intervals? If so, I think the Quartz connector would be you best choice.

Is this the scenario you are after?

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes that's what I want for my application